# Как объединить результат в 1 таблицу и как вставить автоподмену?

Tags: postgresql

В общем нужно с одной таблицы вывести результат:

Это Вася / Марина, он / она имеет [почту]

Таблица имя, гендерный признак, почта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Это ' || name || CASE gender 
                         WHEN 'M' THEN ', он'
                         WHEN 'F' THEN ', она'
                                  ELSE ', оно'
                                  END || ' имеет почту ' || mail result
FROM table
```

Comment: я как рак описал проблему) но решение четкое, спасибо. Могли бы Вы еще подсказать, как вывести результат в 1 таблицу
то есть, например, чтобы все результаты полей выводились в одно поле "Инфо"

инфо
Это марина она имеет почту marina@gmail.com

Comment: @kremenseo Преобразуйте этот запрос в соответствующий UPDATE. `UPDATE table SET info = (вот это вот выражение)`. Ну или как оно там в постгрессе...